# How to check a radio button with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, radio-button

I try to check a radio button with jQuery. Here's my code:

```
<form>
    <div id='type'>
        <input type='radio' id='radio_1' name='type' value='1' />
        <input type='radio' id='radio_2' name='type' value='2' />
        <input type='radio' id='radio_3' name='type' value='3' /> 
    </div>
</form>
```

And the JavaScript:

```
jQuery("#radio_1").attr('checked', true);
```

Doesn't work:

```
jQuery("input[value='1']").attr('checked', true);
```

Doesn't work:

```
jQuery('input:radio[name="type"]').filter('[value="1"]').attr('checked', true);
```

Doesn't work:

Do you have another idea? What am I missing?

Comment: Thanks for your responses!

I found the problem. Actually, the two first ways to do it are working.
The point is I used jqueryUI to transform a set of 3 radio buttons into a button set with this code : 

     jQuery("#type").buttonset();

but making this change before checking the radio was breaking the radio set (don't know why).
Finally, I put the buttonset call after checking the radio and it works impeccably.

Answer (score 1685, accepted):

For versions of jQuery equal or above (>=) 1.6, use:

```
$("#radio_1").prop("checked", true);
```

For versions prior to (<) 1.6, use:

```
$("#radio_1").attr('checked', 'checked');
```

**Tip:** You may also want to call `click()` or `change()` on the radio button afterwards. *See comments for more info.*

Comment: In jQuery 1.9 or higher this solution won't work. Use $("#radio_1").prop("checked", true); instead.

Comment: It helpful to add `.change()` to the end to trigger any other events on the page.

Comment: If you want the other radio buttons in the radio group to update properly use `$("#radio_1").prop("checked", true).trigger("click");`

Answer (score 303):

Try this.

In this example, I'm targeting it with its input name and value

```
$("input[name=background][value='some value']").prop("checked",true);
```

Good to know: in case of multi-word value, it will work because of apostrophes, too.

Comment: For some reason this one worked for me for one troublesome radio group when just using the ID didn't work.

Comment: @MichaelK maybe there's another element that has same id and it is not an input type?

Comment: I looked for that, but there is nothing else with the same id. It is strange. I notice in the source I have "checked" for the originally checked radio button. But in the inspector I see it is checked="" so I wonder if that difference means anything.

Answer (score 101):

Short and easy to read option:

```
$("#radio_1").is(":checked")
```

It returns `true` or `false`, so you can use it in "if" statement.

Comment: Thanks! This is what I was looking for, but (FYI) the OP was asking how to SET the radio button, not get the value. (The word "check" made the question confusing.)

Answer (score 98):

One more function prop() that is added in jQuery 1.6, that serves the same purpose.

```
$("#radio_1").prop("checked", true);
```

Comment: the `attr('checked', true)` stopped working for me with jQuery 1.9, this is the solution!

Answer (score 36):

Try this.

To check Radio button using ***Value*** use this.

```
$('input[name=type][value=2]').attr('checked', true);
```

Or

```
$('input[name=type][value=2]').attr('checked', 'checked');
```

Or

```
$('input[name=type][value=2]').prop('checked', 'checked');
```

To check Radio button using ***ID*** use this.

```
$('#radio_1').attr('checked','checked');
```

Or

```
$('#radio_1').prop('checked','checked');
```

Answer (score 24):

Use **prop()** mehtod

[image]

**Source [Link](https://www.freakyjolly.com/how-to-check-a-radio-button-in-a-group-with-jquery/)**

```
<p>
    <h5>Radio Selection</h5>

    <label>
        <input type="radio" name="myRadio" value="1"> Option 1
    </label>
    <label>
        <input type="radio" name="myRadio" value="2"> Option 2
    </label>
    <label>
        <input type="radio" name="myRadio" value="3"> Option 3
    </label>
</p>

<p>
    <button>Check Radio Option 2</button>
</p>


<script>
    $(function () {

        $("button").click(function () {
            $("input:radio[value='2']").prop('checked',true);
        });

    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 17):

The `$.prop` way is better:

```
$(document).ready(function () {                            
    $("#radio_1").prop('checked', true);        
});
```

and you can test it like the following:

```
$(document).ready(function () {                            
    $("#radio_1, #radio_2", "#radio_3").change(function () {
        if ($("#radio_1").is(":checked")) {
            $('#div1').show();
        }
        else if ($("#radio_2").is(":checked")) {
            $('#div2').show();
        }
        else 
            $('#div3').show();
    });        
});
```

Answer (score 17):

Try This:

```
$("input[name=type]").val(['1']);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/nwo706xw/

Comment: Importantly `.val(['1'])` not `.val('1')`

Answer (score 16):

Surprisingly, the most popular and accepted answer ignores triggering appropriate event despite of the comments. **Make sure you invoke** `.change()`, otherwise all the "on change" bindings will ignore this event.

```
$("#radio_1").prop("checked", true).change();
```

Answer (score 9):

You have to do

```
jQuery("#radio_1").attr('checked', 'checked');
```

That's the HTML attribute

Answer (score 9):

This answer is thanks to Paul LeBeau in [a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5665915/how-to-check-a-radio-button-with-jquery#comment60198421_5665942). I thought I'd write it up as a proper answer since there surprisingly wasn't one.

The only thing that worked for me (jQuery 1.12.4, Chrome 86) was:

```js
$(".js-my-radio-button").trigger("click");
```

This does everything I want – changes which radio button looks selected (both visually and programmatically) and triggers events such as `change` on the radio button.

Just setting the "checked" attribute as other answers suggest would not change which radio button was selected for me.

Answer (score 7):

If property `name` does not work don't forget that `id` still exists. This answer is for people who wants to target the `id` here how you do.

```
$('input[id=element_id][value=element_value]').prop("checked",true);
```

Because property `name` does not work for me. Make sure you don't surround `id` and `name` with double/single quotations.

Cheers!

Answer (score 7):

Try this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("input[name='type']:radio").change(function(){
        if($(this).val() == '1')
        {
          // do something
        }
        else if($(this).val() == '2')
        {
          // do something
        }
        else if($(this).val() == '3')
        {
          // do something
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 7):

```
$("input[name=inputname]:radio").click(function() {
    if($(this).attr("value")=="yes") {
        $(".inputclassname").show();
    }
    if($(this).attr("value")=="no") {
        $(".inputclassname").hide();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 7):

We should want to tell it is a `radio` button.So please try with following code.

```
$("input[type='radio'][name='userRadionButtonName']").prop('checked', true);
```

Answer (score 7):

Yes, it worked for me like a way:

```
$("#radio_1").attr('checked', 'checked');
```

Answer (score 7):

Just in case anyone is trying to achieve this while using jQuery UI, you will also need to refresh the UI checkbox object to reflect the updated value:

```
$("#option2").prop("checked", true); // Check id option2
$("input[name='radio_options']").button("refresh"); // Refresh button set
```

Answer (score 6):

Get value:

```
$("[name='type'][checked]").attr("value");
```

Set value:

```
$(this).attr({"checked":true}).prop({"checked":true});
```

Radio Button click add attr checked:

```
$("[name='type']").click(function(){
  $("[name='type']").removeAttr("checked");
  $(this).attr({"checked":true}).prop({"checked":true});
});
```

Answer (score 6):

Try this with example

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="myForm">
<input type="radio" name="radio" value="first"/> 1 <br/>
<input type="radio" name="radio" value="second"/> 2 <br/>
</form>


<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#myForm').on('click', function () {
        var value = $("[name=radio]:checked").val();

        alert(value);
    })
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 5):

## I use this code:

I'm sorry for English.

```js
var $j = jQuery.noConflict();

$j(function() {
    // add handler
    $j('#radio-1, #radio-2').click(function(){

        // find all checked and cancel checked
        $j('input:radio:checked').prop('checked', false);

        // this radio add cheked
        $j(this).prop('checked', true);
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<fieldset class="section">
  <legend>Radio buttons</legend>
  <label>
    <input type="radio" id="radio-1" checked>
    Option one is this and that&mdash;be sure to include why it's great
  </label>
  <br>
  <label>
    <input type="radio" id="radio-2">
    Option two can be something else
  </label>
</fieldset>
```

Answer (score 4):

Try this

```
var isChecked = $("#radio_1")[0].checked;
```

Answer (score 4):

I've just have a similar problem, a simple solution is to just use:

```
.click()
```

Any other solution will work if you refresh radio after calling function.

Comment: call click sometimes is a headache in ie9

Answer (score 4):

```
function rbcitiSelction(e) {
     debugger
    $('#trpersonalemail').hide();
    $('#trcitiemail').show();
}

function rbpersSelction(e) {
    var personalEmail = $(e).val();
    $('#trpersonalemail').show();
    $('#trcitiemail').hide();
}

$(function() {  
    $("#citiEmail").prop("checked", true)
});
```

Answer (score 4):

**In addition, you can check if the element is checked or not:**

```
if ($('.myCheckbox').attr('checked'))
{
   //do others stuff
}
else
{
   //do others stuff
}
```

**You can checked for unchecked element:**

```
$('.myCheckbox').attr('checked',true) //Standards way
```

**You can also uncheck this way:**

```
$('.myCheckbox').removeAttr('checked')
```

> You can checked for radio button:

For versions of jQuery equal or above (>=) 1.6, use:

```
$("#radio_1").prop("checked", true);
```

For versions prior to (<) 1.6, use:

```
$("#radio_1").attr('checked', 'checked');
```

Answer (score 3):

```
$("#radio_1").attr('checked', true);
//or
$("#radio_1").attr('checked', 'checked');
```

Comment: `$("#radio_1").attr('checked', true);` this won't work. As mentioned by the OP

Comment: Please explain the code in your answers, and read the question (this has been tried)

Answer (score 3):

I got some related example to be enhanced, how about if I want to add a new condition, lets say, if I want colour scheme to be hidden after I click on project Status value except Pavers and Paving Slabs.

Example is in here:

```
$(function () {
    $('#CostAnalysis input[type=radio]').click(function () {
        var value = $(this).val();

        if (value == "Supply & Lay") {
            $('#ul-suplay').empty();
            $('#ul-suplay').append('<fieldset data-role="controlgroup"> \
```

http://jsfiddle.net/m7hg2p94/4/

Answer (score 3):

attr accepts two strings.

The correct way is:

```
jQuery("#radio_1").attr('checked', 'true');
```

Answer (score 3):

I used **jquery-1.11.3.js**

**Basic Enable & disable**

> **Tips 1:  (Radio button type common Disable & Enable)**

```
$("input[type=radio]").attr('disabled', false);
$("input[type=radio]").attr('disabled', true);
```

> **Tips 2: ( ID selector Using prop() or attr())**

```
$("#paytmradio").prop("checked", true);
$("#sbiradio").prop("checked", false);

jQuery("#paytmradio").attr('checked', 'checked'); // or true this won't work
jQuery("#sbiradio").attr('checked', false);
```

> **Tips 3: ( Class selector Using prop() or arrt())**

```
$(".paytm").prop("checked", true);
$(".sbi").prop("checked", false);

jQuery(".paytm").attr('checked', 'checked'); // or true
jQuery(".sbi").attr('checked', false);
```

> **OTHER TIPS**

```
$("#paytmradio").is(":checked")   // Checking is checked or not
$(':radio:not(:checked)').attr('disabled', true); // All not check radio button disabled

$('input[name=payment_type][value=1]').attr('checked', 'checked'); //input type via checked
 $("input:checked", "#paytmradio").val() // get the checked value
```

*index.html*

```
<div class="col-md-6">      
    <label class="control-label" for="paymenttype">Payment Type <span style="color:red">*</span></label>
    <div id="paymenttype" class="form-group" style="padding-top: inherit;">
        <label class="radio-inline" class="form-control"><input  type="radio" id="paytmradio"  class="paytm" name="paymenttype" value="1" onclick="document.getElementById('paymentFrm').action='paytmTest.php';">PayTM</label>
        <label class="radio-inline" class="form-control"><input  type="radio" id="sbiradio" class="sbi" name="paymenttype" value="2" onclick="document.getElementById('paymentFrm').action='sbiTest.php';">SBI ePAY</label>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
 $("input:checked", "#radioButton").val()
```

if checked returns `True`
if not checked returns `False`

```
jQuery v1.10.1
```

Answer (score 2):

Some times above solutions do not work, then you can try below:

```
jQuery.uniform.update(jQuery("#yourElementID").attr('checked',true));
jQuery.uniform.update(jQuery("#yourElementID").attr('checked',false));
```

Another way you can try is:

```
jQuery("input:radio[name=yourElementName]:nth(0)").attr('checked',true);
```

Comment: [Uniform](http://uniformjs.com/) is a jQuery plugin that makes forms prettier, but it does that by adding extra elements. Whenever I update the checked value, the extra element state is not updated, leading to an invisible input that is not checked, but with a visible background element that looks checked. `jQuery.uniform.update()` is the solution!

Answer (score 1):

Try This:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#Id").prop("checked", true).checkboxradio('refresh');
});
```

Comment: This won't work without including the file for the `checkboxradio` plugin, which is pointless when you can just use jQuery's built in functions to accomplish this (see accepted answer).

Answer (score 1):

In case you don't want to include a big library like jQuery for something this simple, here's an alternative solution using built-in DOM methods:

```js
// Check checkbox by id:
document.querySelector('#radio_1').checked = true;

// Check checkbox by value:
document.querySelector('#type > [value="1"]').checked = true;

// If this is the only input with a value of 1 on the page, you can leave out the #type >
document.querySelector('[value="1"]').checked = true;
```

```html
<form>
    <div id='type'>
        <input type='radio' id='radio_1' name='type' value='1' />
        <input type='radio' id='radio_2' name='type' value='2' />
        <input type='radio' id='radio_3' name='type' value='3' /> 
    </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score -4):

## Shortest

```
radio_1.checked
```

```js
checkBtn.onclick = e=> {
  console.log( radio_1.checked );
}
```

```html
Select first radio and click button
<!-- Question html -->
<form>
    <div id='type'>
        <input type='radio' id='radio_1' name='type' value='1' />
        <input type='radio' id='radio_2' name='type' value='2' />
        <input type='radio' id='radio_3' name='type' value='3' /> 
    </div>
</form>

<!-- Test html -->
<button id="checkBtn">Check</button>
```

jsfiddle snippet [here](https://jsfiddle.net/Lamik/rof6ahk2/)

Comment: Some guys give minus points without comment - but this short solution actually works