# How to change a radio button value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, radio-button

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [how to check a radio button with jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5665915/how-to-check-a-radio-button-with-jquery)

How to change a radio button value.

```
jQuery('input:radio[name=search][id=search-damages]').checked = true;
```

i have tried this but it is not working

```
<input type="radio" name="search" id="search-vehicle" value="search-vehicle" checked>
<input type="radio" name="search" id="search-damages" value="search-damages">
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> How to change a radio button value?

*`checked`* property doesn't change the value of radio button. note that *`checked`* property is one the DOM INPUT Element properties and not one of the jQuery object properties(*by selecting an element using jQuery, a jQuery object is created*). If you want to change this property you should first convert the jQuery object into a DOM Element object.

```
$('#search-damages')[0].checked = true;
```

or use the jQuery object's `prop()` method:

```
$('#search-damages').prop('checked', true)
```

If you want to change the value of an input you can use the jQuery `val()` method:

```
$('#search-damages').val('new value');
```

Comment: I wish more input-related jQuery questions would more accurately specify to use `prop` instead of `attr`, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I'm a fan of "use jQuery when reduce complexity, use JS in other cases", so I would go for:

```
$("#search-damages")[0].checked = true;
```

Otherwise, if you prefer use jQuery syntanx, you could use:

```
$("#search-damages").prop("checked", true);
```

See: http://api.jquery.com/prop/

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('#search-damages').attr('checked','checked');
```

Comment: Its working you can have a look at the live site: http://jsfiddle.net/MAhmadZ/S4EGX/