# Getting attribute name instead of value - query

Tags: jquery

Using this jquery code:

```
$("#targeting input:radio").each(function() {
   console.log ($(this).attr("selected"));
});
```

HTML:

```
 <input type="radio" id="dateFromTo" name="muScheduleDateRange" value="2" selected="someval"/>
```

In console.log I'm getting `selected` instead `someval`?

Comment: You need to set the `value` to 'Someval' instead of the `selected` as mentioned in meagars answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`selected` is a boolean. You can't set it to anything except `undefined` or `"selected"`. If you want to attach some value to the `input`, use the `value` attribute. If you want to attach some *additional* value to the `input`, use a data attribute.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
console.log($('#targeting input:radio:checked').val())
```

See [jquery val](http://api.jquery.com/val/)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
console.log($(this).prop('checked'));
```

Will return true or false, depending on whether the radio button is checked.

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5665915/how-to-check-a-radio-button-with-jquery)