# if radio button is checked new option will open for file upload or url text input

Tags: javascript, html

i want to create a form where user have two option for image upload , either they upload a image through a file upload option or they can input text URL of the image, the problem is that how can restrict a user to either of the one option, i though RADIO checked might help me but i didn't figure out how to use radio button to enable any of the one option, kindly help me in this, i am new in development and didn't have much knowledge of JavaScript as well.

```
<input name="file" type="radio" value="file" checked><input type="file" name="file">
<input name="file" type="radio" value="url" checked><input type="text" name="url" >
```

Comment: Please post relevant javascript. Also look into this- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5665915/how-to-check-a-radio-button-with-jquery

Comment: @ DOM , i didnt know about anything about javascript, kindly help me in this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this relatively easy. I added a class to your `input` that is going to show depending on the radio (I used `type` as the class), then with simple jQuery:

```
$("input:radio").change(function() {
    $(".type").hide();
    $(this).next("input").show();
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/JvPYv/1/

Comment: @ tymeJV , its not working with complete form, is it possible that we can call it through any id