# Bootstrap 3 radio buttons not submitting to PHP post when click programmatically

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, onclick, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a series of bootstrap radio buttons in a search filter system.
All is working find with a series of onchange and onclick events assoicated when them.

The issues I am having is when  I run a search and repopulate all the radio filters.
The bootstrap radio buttons are outputted the the same normal and `checked="checked"` is added to the selected radio.
I'm then set the relevant label as active and simulate a CLICK trigger event. This runs a series of events critical to the interface.

```
$('input[type="radio"]:checked').parent('label').addClass('active');
//simulate click
$('input[type="radio"]:checked').parent('label').click( );
$('input[type="radio"]:checked').click( );
```

*Note: I have tried various combination of the click trigger

Checking the code it is a correct output. `checked="checked"` is in the radio and the buttons/label is active.

However when I resubmit the form, WITHOUT CLICKING ON THE RADIO, the values for these radio buttons are not in the post. 
They just vanish. This ONLY happens when I run the click tigger. If I click a radio buttons THAT IS NOT SELECTED the value IS submitted in post. If I click on the already active label (already selected) radio the value is not in post. Only if I click a new value after I have run the jquery click trigger.

If I omit the click trigger the radio button values are successfully posted as expected.

When using the click trigger all attached events associated with the click trigger run fine. However when I use the clicks trigger and do not change the value,  the radio just vanishes from the return $_POST.

Why is this? Am I doing something wrong? At this point in development I need the click trigger to function correctly.

Comment: see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5665915/how-to-check-a-radio-button-with-jquery

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue like this :

```
//to check radio on click
$('label.btn.btn-primary').click(function () {
    $(this).children('input').attr("checked", "checked");
});
//to check radio on load
$('label.btn.btn-primary.active').children('input').attr("checked", "checked");
```