# Check a radio button with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, radio-button

For some reason, I can't seem to figure this out.

I have some radio buttons in my html which toggles categories:

```
<input type="radio" name="main-categories" id="_1234" value="1234" /> // All
<input type="radio" name="main-categories" id="_2345" value="2345" /> // Certain category
<input type="radio" name="main-categories" id="_3456" value="3456" /> // Certain category
<input type="radio" name="main-categories" id="_4567" value="4567" /> // Certain category
```

The user can select whichever he/she wants, but when an certain event triggers, I want to set `1234` to be set checked radio button, because this is the default checked radio button.

I have tried versions of this (with and without jQuery):

`document.getElementById('#_1234').checked = true;`

But it doesn't seem to update. I need it to visibly update so the user can see it.
Can anybody help?

EDIT: I'm just tired and overlooked the `#`, thanks for pointing it out, that and `$.prop()`.

Comment: Check this StackOverflow question: [How to check a radio button with jQuery][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5665915/how-to-check-a-radio-button-with-jquery

Comment: change to `document.getElementById('_1234').checked = true;`

Comment: @stackErr without the `#`

Comment: Sorry, just a wrong copy-paste. Updated now. @FelipeKM Then please help me, I've not found one that helps.

Comment: @kjelelokk check my comment or Pointys answer

Comment: how do you wanna select a element by ID passing the wrong id? Remove this '#' before '_1234', this is for query selectors such jQuery $('#_1234')

Answer (score 234, accepted):

Do not mix CSS/JQuery syntax (`#` for identifier) with native JS.

**Native JS solution:**

```
document.getElementById('_1234').checked = true;
```

To also trigger the associated event (e.g. if related controls need to be shown/hidden), call `click()`:

```
document.getElementById('_1234').click();
```

**JQuery solution:**

```
$('#_1234').prop('checked', true);
```

Comment: Technically it's CSS selector syntax. jQuery just borrowed and extended it

Comment: jQuery got it from `querySelector` I would imagine.

Comment: much better than `.attr("checked", "checked")`

Comment: @Andy - Sizzle was used in jQuery from early 2006 onwards. (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JQuery#History). `querySelector` wasn't shipped in browsers until 2009 and wasn't being used widely by developers until some time after that. I've never used jQuery all that much, but it significantly impacted on the evolution of JS.

Comment: this sets the check box but doesn't necessarily trigger the associated event.  what event is triggered when the user clicks a radio button?

Comment: @robisrob Yes, as this only changes the `checked` property of the radio button and does not perform a `click`, `change` or any other event. If you were to use `checkboxSelector.click()`, that would be where you would trigger a click event.

Answer (score 26):

If you want to set the "1234" button, you need to use its "id":

```
document.getElementById("_1234").checked = true;
```

When you're using the browser API ("getElementById"), you don't use selector syntax; you just pass the actual "id" value you're looking for.  You use selector syntax with jQuery or `.querySelector()` and `.querySelectorAll()`.

Comment: everyone is getting the element by ID I have more than one radio buttons with the same name. and I think that's what most people need to select a group of radios by name and then based on value check one of them.

Comment: @NadeemGorsi the "id" attribute cannot be shared by more than one element. All "id" values must be unique on a given page.

Answer (score 21):

Today, in the year 2016, it is safe to use `document.querySelector` without knowing the ID (especially if you have more than 2 radio buttons):

```
document.querySelector("input[name=main-categories]:checked").value
```

Comment: OK, but how can I get the reverse effect or check a radio based on value.. and that's what question was about in fact.

Comment: @NadeemGorsi I provided an answer to select or "check" a radio button using QuerySelector

Comment: TechNerdXp  Try selecting by value instead of name. `document.querySelector('input[value="xyz"])`

Answer (score 6):

Easiest way would probably be with jQuery, as follows:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#_1234").attr("checked","checked");
})
```

This adds a new attribute "checked" (which in HTML does not need a value).
Just remember to include the jQuery library:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Or just `$("#_1234").prop("checked", true)`

Answer (score 4):

By using `document.getElementById()` function you don't have to pass `#` before element's id.

Code:

```
document.getElementById('_1234').checked = true;
```

Demo:
[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jzQvH/)

Answer (score 3):

I was able to select (check) a radio input button by using this Javascript code in Firefox 72, within a Web Extension option page to LOAD the value:

```
var reloadItem = browser.storage.sync.get('reload_mode');
reloadItem.then((response) => {
    if (response["reload_mode"] == "Periodic") {
        document.querySelector('input[name=reload_mode][value="Periodic"]').click();
    } else if (response["reload_mode"] == "Page Bottom") {
        document.querySelector('input[name=reload_mode][value="Page Bottom"]').click();
    } else {
        document.querySelector('input[name=reload_mode][value="Both"]').click();
    }
});
```

Where the associated code to SAVE the value was:

```
reload_mode: document.querySelector('input[name=reload_mode]:checked').value
```

Given HTML like the following:

```
    <input type="radio" id="periodic" name="reload_mode" value="Periodic">
    <label for="periodic">Periodic</label><br>
    <input type="radio" id="bottom" name="reload_mode" value="Page Bottom">
    <label for="bottom">Page Bottom</label><br>
    <input type="radio" id="both" name="reload_mode" value="Both">
    <label for="both">Both</label></br></br>
```

Answer (score 2):

It seems the item.checked property of a HTML radio button cannot be changed with JavaScript in Internet Explorer, or in some older browsers.

I also tried setting the "checked" attribute, using:
`item.setAttribute("checked", "");` I know the property can be set by default,
but I need just to change the checked attribute at runtime.

As a workarround, I found another method, which could be working. I had called the `item.click();` method of a radio button. And the control has been selected. But the control must be already added to the HTML document, in order to receive the click event.

Comment: Nice detail Adrian, but I think the original poster had a much simpler question with a "#" in the wrong place :)

Comment: Thanks for the tip with `item.click()`