# Pass value with link_to to the form on another page in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I need to pass a value for the form with a link_to to the 'new' page in rails.

'New' page form radio buttons code:

```
= f.collection_radio_buttons :model, books.all, :id, :model, :prompt => true, label: "Book"
```

So it will look like list of 5 radio buttons.

And i need pass a value to this radio buttons with:

```
= link_to "New", path_to_new_page
```

is it possible with rails only without javascript?

Comment: Can you give context? Like which page is this and why are you trying to send a request to the new page etc?

Comment: I used this one http://stackoverflow.com/a/21166949/5642865, but NightFall's works as well in case if use form submit.

Comment: Thanks for the update, I'll keep this in mind thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can't you just submit the form? It would be something like this

```
= form_for(@model_object, url: path_to_new_page(@model_object)) do |f|
   = f.collection_radio_buttons :model, books.all, :id, :model, :prompt => true, label: "Book"

   = f.submit "New"
```

You can find examples here -> http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html

If you can't/won't use form submit, you could just capture the click event, and just go to the new page with the parameters collected from the inputs.