# Restore previous state of RadiobuttonList in asp.net

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, telerik

I have a RadioButtonList in asp.net Usercontrol. It contains the values  "Leave", "Available". When the user clicks "Leave", then, I should display message as "Are you sure you want to take Leave?" with "Ok" and "Cancel" buttons.

When the user clicks Available/Leave, then the following event fires.

```
protected void rdlUser_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (rdlUser.SelectedIndex == 0)
    {
            radWindowManager.RadConfirm("Are you sure you want to take Leave?", "confirmSave" + this.ClientID, 300, 100, null, "");
    }
}
```

This is Client side javascript function...

```
function confirmSave<%=this.ClientID%>(arg) {
    if (arg == true) {
        $find('<%= FindControl("txtUser").ClientID %>').set_value("User has taken Leave");
}
```

**If the user clicks Leave Radiobutton and clicks cancel in the confirm message box, then the program should revert the change to "Available" Radiobutton. How can I select that "Available" programatically in Server/Client side?

EDIT:The main goal is to reset the value to previous state**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add an else statement to catch `arg==false` and set the `checked` property of the desired radio input to `true`. See [Check a radio button with javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21166860/check-a-radio-button-with-javascript)

Comment: I have a problem here. The Radiobuttons "Available" and "Leave" of RadiobuttonList are coming from database. It can be more than 2 values("Available" & "Leave"). I need to identify that in client javascript and  set the value of it programatically. I need to use similar code like this because it is a UserControl `$find('<%= FindControl("txtUser").ClientID %>')`

Comment: use unique names for the JS functions (http://www.telerik.com/support/kb/aspnet-ajax/details/using-dynamic-unique-names-for-javascript-functions) and inject the needed ID with a server code block in each instance