# How to detect the radio button's value change without resubmit the form?

Tags: javascript, html, css, radio-button, forms

I've got 2 radio buttons within a form here,

```
<form action='' method='post' onsubmit='return checkForm(this, event)'>
     <input type = 'radio' name='allow' value='allow' checked>Allow
     <input type='radio' name='allow' value='disallow'>Disallow
</form>
```

And in the checkForm function, there is a piece of code to verify whether the user checks the Disallow button, if yes, show an alert to force the user to allow, if not, return true.

Yet, I found that when I first checked the **Disallow** button, and the sign showed, and then I change it to **Allow**, but there is still the alert sign popping saying that I should alter my choice to **Allow**

This is the checkForm function:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function checkForm(form, event) {
        var radio  = document.getElementsByName("allow");
        var counter=0;
        for(i=0;i<radio.length;i++){
            if(radio[i].value=="disallow"){
                alert("Please allow the system to get your data!");
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;    
    }
</script>
```

Any ideas? Thanks a lot.

Comment: The attribute you want to test is checked, not value. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21166860/check-a-radio-button-with-javascript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to check if the option is checked or not:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function checkForm(form, event) {
    var radio  = document.getElementsByName("allow");
    var counter=0;
    for(i=0;i<radio.length;i++){
        if(radio[i].checked && radio[i].value=="disallow") {
            alert("Please allow the system to get your data!");
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;    
}
</script>
```

Modern browsers:

```
function checkForm(form, event) {
    if(document.querySelector('input[name="allow"]:checked').value=="disallow") {
        alert("Please allow the system to get your data!");
        return false;
    }

    return true;    
}
```

Comment: thank you very much for the reply! It really helped a lot!

Answer (score 0):

I think I found some things wrong with your HTML code:

```
<input type='radio' name='allow' value='disallow' Disallow
```

This tag is not closed, it should be

```
<input type='radio' name='allow' value='disallow'> Disallow
```

Also, what version of HTML are you using? If you're using HTML5 or XHTML Strict, then you need to self-close:

```
<input type='radio' name='allow' value='disallow' /> Disallow
```