# Click() function not working in wordpress Javascript

Tags: javascript, wordpress

i want to click a radio element automatically with js. Element selection is perfect because when i try to change it with innerHTML, it changes but click() does not work.

**Code:**

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(){
    document.querySelector(".jet-radio-list__label").innerHTML = "Changed!"
    document.querySelector(".jet-radio-list__label").click()
}
```

**Tried Alternatives like:**

```
document.querySelectorAll('input[type="radio"]').checked = true;
```

**My DOM element which I want to target:**
[image]

Comment: Could you add the HTML for the radio buttons?

Comment: `querySelectorAll` returns array, so `querySelectorAll()[0].checked = true`. Better use proper ID's for each radio button

Comment: Added DOM image in the question. Please review. Its wordpress so please keep in mind that i do not have much control over HTML.

Comment: @Justinas  I totally have 2 radio inputs on whole page & I want both of them to get this js applied. I do not have control over HTML because i am using wordpress & elementor so we'll need a workaroud maybe. How can i do that?

Comment: Prefered way as chrwahl mentioned is to check radio button: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21166860/check-a-radio-button-with-javascript Note: You are also clicking `jet-radio-list__label` instead of `jet-radio-list__input`

Comment: I tried <code>jet-radio-list__input</code> as well but no luck there as well

Comment: Try to execute the command in console. If it works then there is something wrong with loading of js or something catches the event and discards it. If it does not work tell us what error you get.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe something like the following?:

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
    document.querySelectorAll('input[type="radio"]').forEach(
      (input) => input.checked = true
    );
});
```

```css
label { display: block; }
```

```html
<form>
  <label>Radio 1 (field1) <input type="radio" name="field1" value="1" /></label>
  <label>Radio 2 (field1) <input type="radio" name="field1" value="2" /></label>
  <br />
  <label>Radio 3 (field2) <input type="radio" name="field2" value="3" /></label>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot click a radio button, but you can set the element to "checked". And then you can dispatch an event if that is needed.

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', e => {
  document.forms.test.radio01.addEventListener('change', e => {
    console.log(e.target);
  });

  document.forms.test.radio01.checked = true;
  let change_event = new Event('change');
  document.forms.test.radio01.dispatchEvent(change_event);
});
```

```html
<form name="test">
  <label id="label01">Radio01: <input type="radio" name="radio01" /></label>
</form>
```

Comment: Tried this as well but it is not working.

Comment: @ZaeemJaved I did an update if that helps.