# RadioButton wont set checked javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I dont know why the radiobutton wont set checked. I tried all the methods i could find but it won't work.

How I want it to work is that Type1 radiobutton is set checked if the value is 1; if the value is 0, Type2 radiobutton is set checked.

I printed the value in a textfield. The value is from a database btw. Nothing's wrong with getting the value from the database and printing it in the textfield.

My only problem is setting the radio buttons checked based on the value in the textfield.

I put an alert() in the function but it seems that it wont display an alert too. I think it doesn't call the function from the commmon.js. But other functions in common.js works though. :/

Here's the code;

**common.js**

```
var selected;

function SetRadiobuttonValue()
{
    selected = document.getElementById('myType').value;
    alert(selected);
    if(selected == "" || selected == 0){
        document.getElementById("type1").checked = true;
        document.getElementById("type2").checked = false;
    }else if(selected == 1){
        document.getElementById("type1").checked = false;
        document.getElementById("type2").checked = true;
    }
}
```

**form.jsp**

```
    <input type="text" id="myType" name="admin" value="${usersModule.adminFlag}" onChange=" SetRadiobuttonValue()">
    <label><input type="radio" name="type" id="type1" value="0" > General User</label>
    <label><input type="radio" name="type" id="type2" value="1" > Admin</label>
```

**To those who tried to answer but still wont work:**

I have another example: Imagine editing a profile form and there is the radio buttons of Male and Female. If it is Male in the profile info, the Male radio button is set checked or vice versa.

That's what i want to happen. But the radio button wont set checked. :(

**UPDATE**

I found the answer now. Thanks to @ketan :D I just have to put the function on body tag onLoad event to make it work. :D

Comment: checked=checked

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5665915/how-to-check-a-radio-button-with-jquery

Comment: You have used the attribute of `name` not `id` in this line `document.getElementById('admin').value;`

Comment: I tried that checked=checked thing . It wont work

Comment: i didnt realize that i put the wrong id. I'll try to see if it works now.

Comment: It still wont work :(

Comment: @Ruby Check this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/sp0ro8op/

Comment: Still wont set though. :( I dont think i should wait for onChange event. What i want is that as the document finish load the button is set checked.

Comment: Show us how you calling SetRadiobuttonValue?

Comment: i put it on OnchangeEvent. just like the code u shared.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

please try this i run this code in all browser
in this code onload javascript event i call ch() function
in ch()function i set radio button is checked the javascript

```html
<html>
<head>
 <title>check radio button</title>
 <script type="text/javascript">
  function ch()
  {
   document.getElementById("rd1").checked = true;
  }
 </script>
</head>
<body onload="ch();">
 <input type="radio" name="rd1" value="radio1" id="rd1">radio1
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: THIS WORKS. SOLVED MY PROBLEM. THANKS :D

Answer (score 1):

maybe your script runs before DOM nodes are ready,try moving `<script> SetRadiobuttonValue();</script>` after your label and input tags

Answer (score 1):

With JQuery

```js
$('#myType').on('input', function() {
  var val = this.value;
  var rdo = $('input[name=type]:eq(0)');
  if (val)
    rdo = $('input[name=type][value=' + val + ']');
  rdo.prop('checked', true);
}).trigger('input');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="myType" name="admin" value="0">
<label>
  <input type="radio" name="type" id="type1" value="0">General User</label>
<label>
  <input type="radio" name="type" id="type2" value="1">Admin</label>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>

<script>
    function SetRadiobuttonValue() {
        var selected;
        selected = document.getElementById('myType').value;

        if (selected == "1") {
            document.getElementById("type1").checked = true;
            document.getElementById("type2").checked = false;
        } else if (selected == "0") {
            document.getElementById("type1").checked = false;
            document.getElementById("type2").checked = true;
        }
    }

</script>
</head>
<body>

 <input type="text" id="myType" name="admin" value="" onChange=" SetRadiobuttonValue()">
    <label><input type="radio" name="type" id="type1" value="0" > General User</label>
    <label><input type="radio" name="type" id="type2" value="1" > Admin</label>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: i have already tried this too. But it doesnt solved my problem.

Comment: did u include that common.js??

Answer (score 1):

Your updated code : just one change see my comment

```
var selected;

    function SetRadiobuttonValue()
    {
        selected = document.getElementById('myType').value;

        if(selected == "" || selected == "0"){ // change here --- 0 to "0"
            document.getElementById("type1").checked = true;
            document.getElementById("type2").checked = false;
        }else if(selected == "1"){ // change here --- 1 to "1"
            document.getElementById("type1").checked = false;
            document.getElementById("type2").checked = true;
        }
    }
```

//More improved answer:

```
var selected;
function SetRadiobuttonValue(){
     selected = document.getElementById('myType').value;
     $('input:radio[name="type"]').filter("[value=" + selected + "]").prop("checked", "checked");
}
```

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/uLfp4rkz/3/)

Answer (score 1):

Your'e only a couple of extra lines of code away, you were very close:

- You had 2 conditionals `if` and `else if`, so you needed an `else`.

  - When you have 2 `if`-ish conditionals, then use `if` and `else`,
  - and if you have more than 2, then start with `if` continue using `else if` until the last conditional being `else`.
- Made `var selected` into a number:

  - `selected = parseInt(document.getElementById('admin').value, 10);`
- Added an `eventListener` on the text input.
- Made the form a little fancy.
- BTW, the demo below is functional as well. Enter a 0 and the first radio is checked, enter a 1 and the second radio is checked. The other condition "" (empty string?) is hard to replicate on a change or input event.
- You can view the console output with developer tools.

**Note:** I changed `#myType` to `#admin`

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>SO34984810</title>
</head>

<body>
  <form id="formSet" name="formSet" method="" action="">
    <fieldset>
      <legend>User Groups</legend>
      <input type="text" id="admin" name="admin" value="">
      <label>
        <input type="radio" name="type" id="type1" value="0">General User</label>
      <label>
        <input type="radio" name="type" id="type2" value="1">Admin</label>
    </fieldset>



    <script>
      function SetRadiobuttonValue(selected) {
        var out1 = document.getElementById('out1');
        selected = parseInt(document.getElementById('admin').value, 10);
        console.log('selected: ' + selected);
        if (selected === "" || selected === 0) {
          document.getElementById("type1").checked = true;
          document.getElementById("type2").checked = false;
          console.log('type1: ' + document.getElementById("type1").checked);
        } else if (selected === 1) {
          document.getElementById("type1").checked = false;
          document.getElementById("type2").checked = true;
          console.log('type2: ' + document.getElementById("type2").checked);
        } else {
          console.log(selected + ' is INVALID');
          return false;
        }
      }

      document.getElementById('admin').addEventListener('input', function(e) {
        var sel = this.value;
        SetRadiobuttonValue(sel);
      }, false);
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: whats the e in function(e)?

Comment: It is [`event`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event) object like `event.target` or `event.preventDefault()` like any parameter in JS, it doesn't have to be used. I put it in there as a reflexive habit. You might also see it as `function(event) {` or `function(evt) {`as well.

Comment: this is not what i want. the textfied has already the value. I dont need to input a value to set the radio button. What i mean is that as document loads, it will check what value is in the textfield and set checked corresponding button . Imagine editing a profile form and there is the radio buttons of Male and Female. If it is Male in the profile info, the Male radio button is set checked or vice versa.

Comment: Ok, that's easy so you just want the var selected to be entered on load?

Comment: yes and also when there is a change, the value is change in the textfield as well. All the answers here is only waiting for the change event in the textfield to set checked the radio button. Which doesnt solve my problem. :(

Comment: My solution auto checks the radio according to the input of text, do you want me to put an eventListener on the radios and the value be reflected in the text box as well?

Comment: no need. i already found the answer. thanks for helping me though :)

Answer (score 1):

You can try in this way.

JS :

```
window.onload = function(){

            var selected;

            var myType = document.getElementById('myType');


            myType.addEventListener('change', function ()
            {
                selected = document.getElementById('myType').value;
                alert(selected);
                if(selected == "" || selected == 0){
                    document.getElementById("type1").checked = true;
                    document.getElementById("type2").checked = false;
                }else if(selected == 1){
                    document.getElementById("type1").checked = false;
                    document.getElementById("type2").checked = true;
                }
            }); 
        }
```

HTML :

```
<input type="text" id="myType" name="admin" value="1">
<label><input type="radio" name="type" id="type1" value="0" > General User</label>
<label><input type="radio" name="type" id="type2" value="1" > Admin</label>
```

Here is the [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/zI87I6CJ4rwV1jVzGD58?p=preview)

Comment: didnt set checked the radio button. still the same problem as mine :(

Comment: have you checked plunker?

Comment: i did. same problem as mine

Comment: What problem are you facing?Will you share it.Did you  checked console of browser?

Comment: i added another explanation in my problem