# How to check and select radio buttons by title using jquery

Tags: jquery

I've attempted with the following code, to check if three radio buttons are checked, then check one if none in the set are:

```
if ($('input[title="a"]:selected').length == 0 
        && $('input[title="b"]:selected').length == 0
        && $('input[title="c"]:selected').length == 0
    ) {
        console.log("Nothing checked");
        $('input[title="b"]').prop("checked",true);
    }
}
```

it logs in the console every time (regardless of their states) and doesn't check the radio button.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to check a radio button with jQuery ?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5665915/how-to-check-a-radio-button-with-jquery)

Comment: `:selected` != `:checked`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably don't want to use `:selected`. [jQuery doc says](https://api.jquery.com/selected-selector/):

> The :selected selector works for  elements. It does not work for checkboxes or radio inputs; use :checked for them.

so use `:checked` instead. https://api.jquery.com/checked-selector/

Checking the radio button is explained here [How to check a radio button with jQuery ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5665915/how-to-check-a-radio-button-with-jquery) but the problem is probably somewhere else.

Are you sure the attribute selector matches the `input`? Try dumping its results because I guess it doesn't:

```
 console.log($('input[title="b"]'));
```