# Change Radio Buttons using Jquery

Tags: jquery, html, radio-button

I have a radio button select in my UI.

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="inputEditActive" class="col-lg-2 control-label"></label>
    <div class="col-lg-1">
        <input type="radio" name="radioItem" id="radioItemActive"/>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-1">Active</div>
    <div class="col-lg-1"></div>
    <div class="col-lg-1">
        <input type="radio" name="radioItem" id="radioItemDeactive"/>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-1">Deactive</div>
</div>
```

I want to check one of these buttons using jQuery.

So far I tried different methods that I found on the Internet, but nothing has worked properly.

Can someone please help me with this. Thank you.

Comment: include what you have tried

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to check a radio button with jQuery ?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5665915/how-to-check-a-radio-button-with-jquery)

Answer (score 0):

make use of .prop to check the readio button

```
$("#radioItemDeactive").prop('checked', true);
```

```js
$(function(){
  $("#radioItemDeactive").prop('checked', true);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group">
     <label for="inputEditActive" class="col-lg-2 control-label"></label>
            <div class="col-lg-1">
                 <input type="radio" name="radioItem" id="radioItemActive"/>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-1">Active</div>
            <div class="col-lg-1"></div>
            <div class="col-lg-1">
                 <input type="radio" name="radioItem" id="radioItemDeactive"/>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-1">Deactive</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I did exactly the same. Even-though the code runs without errors, radiobuttons remain unchecked.

Comment: are you doing this inside a `document.ready()` function or `$(function(){})` because it should happen after the component has mounted