# how to checked in checkbox using jquery?

Tags: jquery

i'm new in jquery and i dont know how to use it, this is code i create look like

```
<div id="checkbox-container">
    <div class="hidefull">
        <input type="checkbox" value="hideFull" id="check-hide-full-table">Hide Full
    </div>
    <div class="hideempty">
        <input type="checkbox" value="hideEmpty" id="check-hide-empty-table">Hide Empty
        </div>
</div>
```

and jquery i create like this

```
function test(){
    alert("test called");
    $("#check-hide-empty-table").prop("checked", true);
}
```

so the problem is, how to checked checkbox using jquery? i'm already look [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5665915/how-to-check-a-radio-button-with-jquery) but still not checked. somebody know what's wrong with my code?

i want create if load new page, that checkbox, checked.

FYI, that alert showed.

Comment: You have an extra `,` in your `prop("checked", true)`. Remove it and this should work fine.

Comment: ah sry, my code is not have extra `,` but still not working.i just typo, i'm already edit my question,

Comment: when are you calling your `test` function?

Comment: I've [**copy & pasted**](https://jsfiddle.net/41n1aat3/) your code exactly into a JSFiddle and it seems to be working fine. Are you sure you're including jQuery? Are you getting any errors when you look in console? Are you calling `test();` in a `$(document).ready(...)` to ensure that the element exists when you try to check it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Setting "checked" for a checkbox with jQuery?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/426258/setting-checked-for-a-checkbox-with-jquery)

Comment: ah thanks to make me sure about my code is correct @Santi

Comment: yeah i figure it out, is my mistake wrongly called test function @jkris, i called test function before i load my checkbox

Answer (score 0):

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {

    test("#check-hide-empty-table");

});

function test(input){

    alert("test called");

    testInput = jQuery(input);
    testInput.click(function(){
        if(this.checked != true) {

            alert('not checked');
            return false;
        }

        alert('checked');
        return true;

    });

}
```

Answer (score -1):

Here is the solution: [Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/thefto_dev/9yuxq0hs/1/)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('input').on('change', function() {
      if ($(this).attr("checked")) {
          $(this).attr("checked", false);
      } else {
          $(this).attr("checked", true);
      }
   });
});
```

When checkbox is checked it, It add attribute checked and if unchecked it take out the check