# Select all radio buttons in list-Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a list that has 2 radio buttons against it. I need to randomly select radio buttons in that list. Each radio button (rb1: yes and rb2: no) has different ids. Here's my code.

```
$("#rbList").each(function () {                                                                
            var radios = $(this).find("input[type=radio]");
            if (radios.length > 0) {
                var randomnumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * radios.length);
                $(radios[randomnumber]).trigger('click');
            }
        });
```

This works to select one radio button in the group. What I  don't understand is how to loop it to randomly select all the radio buttons in the list (be it either **yes** or **no**). What do I have to add? Also, I need to automate that. Like just hit enter in console and it should reflect on the page. Any help is greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5665915/how-to-check-a-radio-button-with-jquery Check here. Don't need to trigger a click on it, only set the attr/prop.

Comment: Try `radios.eq(randomnumber).prop("checked", true)`  better if you can share HTML

Comment: Instead of the `$.each` set on the `#rbList`, set it on the common class for each group.

Comment: And you are looping through an element whose length is ONE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this for triggering check and uncheck

```
$("#YourRadioID").prop("checked", true)
```

In your Case :

```
       $("#rbList").each(function () {                                                                
            var radios = $(this).find("input[type=radio]");
            if (radios.length > 0) {
                var randomnumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * radios.length);
                $(radios[randomnumber]).prop("checked", true);
            }
        });
```

for older version you have to use

```
$("#YourRadioID").attr('checked', 'checked');
```

Comment: `$("#rbList").each`.....Really? If it just one element then looping is not required.