# I can't select radio with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, radio-button

I would checked radio with javascript. But i can't.

I tried :

```
document.forms["formisim"]["radio1id"].checked = true;

document.formisim.radio1name.value = "indirimli";

$("#radio1id").prop("checked", true);
```

HTML code

```
   <form name="formisim">
    <input type="radio" 
           class="indirimsizb" 
           name="radio1name" 
           id="indirimsizid" 
           value="indirimsiz" 
           onchange="iindirim()"
           checked> 
    <input type="radio" 
           class="indirimlib" 
           name="radio1name" 
           id="radio1id" 
           value="indirimli"
           onchange="iindirim()">
</form>
```

How can i resolve this?

I need your help.

Comment: please share the html code

Comment: Have you check this [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5665915/how-to-check-a-radio-button-with-jquery) link? Even otherwise, some context around how your HTML page looks like, would be helpful.

Comment: @brk <form name="formisim">

 <input type="radio" class="indirimsizb" name="radio1name" id="indirimsizid" value="indirimsiz" onchange="iindirim()" checked>
 <input type="radio" class="indirimlib" name="radio1name" id="radio1id" value="indirimli" onchange="iindirim()">

 </form>

Comment: Post this in your question, not the comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All the methods that you tried will work.

1) Using the `document.forms` collection:

```
document.forms["formisim"]["radio1id"].checked
```

2) Using the IDs as properties. Notice that you must use the ID, not the name like you did. The form name can be used, though. Also for some reason, you used the `value` here instead of `checked`. Both will work, but give you different values of course:

```
document.formisim.radio1id.value
```

3) Using jQuery with ID selector:

```
$("#radio1id").prop("checked")
```

4) Also, similar to jQuery above, you can use `getElementById()` with the ID:

```
document.getElementById("radio1id").checked
```

Here is a demo of all these methods:

```js
console.log(document.forms["formisim"]["radio1id"].checked);
console.log(document.formisim.radio1id.value);
console.log($("#radio1id").prop("checked"));
console.log(document.getElementById("radio1id").checked);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form name="formisim">
  <input type="radio" class="indirimsizb" name="radio1name" id="indirimsizid" value="indirimsiz" onchange="iindirim()" checked>
  <input type="radio" class="indirimlib" name="radio1name" id="radio1id" value="indirimli" onchange="iindirim()">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

this is javascript code -

```
document.getElementById("radioid").checked = true;
```

this is jquerycode -

```
$("#radioid").prop("checked", true);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `name` attribute selector

```js
document.forms[name = "formisim"]["radio1id"].checked = true;
```

```html
<form name="formisim">
  <input type="radio" class="indirimsizb" name="radio1name" id="indirimsizid" value="indirimsiz" onchange="iindirim()" checked>
  <input type="radio" class="indirimlib" name="radio1name" id="radio1id" value="indirimli" onchange="iindirim()">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

check this snippet working on radio button

```js
$("#radio1id").attr("checked", true);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form name="formisim">
    <input type="radio" 
           class="indirimsizb" 
           name="radio1name" 
           id="indirimsizid" 
           value="indirimsiz" 
           onchange="iindirim()"
           checked> <text>asd</text>
    <input type="radio" 
           class="indirimlib" 
           name="radio1name" 
           id="radio1id" 
           value="indirimli"
           onchange="iindirim()">
           <text>bsd</text>
</form>
```