# selecting a radio button by jquery (by value or by id)

Tags: javascript, jquery

i am trying to select a radio button by JQUERY, but i am not able to do so. i tried using these but its not working.

```
$("#agencyBill").prop("checked", true);
$radios.filter('[value=Agency Bill]').prop('checked', true);
$("[name=customRadio]").filter("[value='Agency Bill]']").attr("checked","checked");
```

[here is fiddle link of the same](https://jsfiddle.net/974duyzb/9/)

i need to select it either by its value or by its id anyone will do.

Comment: `value="Agency Bill"` you need to wrap the value in quotes.

Comment: @Jai thanks for responding i tried using
$radios.filter("value=Agency Bill").prop('checked', true);
$("[name=customRadio]").filter("[value=Agency Bill").attr("checked","checked");

its still not working

Comment: see i have posted one answer.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to check a radio button with jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5665915/how-to-check-a-radio-button-with-jquery)

Comment: Please read this https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your source is actually work OK, what you miss is Jquery library:
Using this will OK:

```
$("#agencyBill").prop("checked", true);
```

but need to add Jquery library first:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: thanks this resolved my problem. actually i was importing jquery.min.js from wrong source in my project too... thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try this : You can put both name and value attribute selector in one and use `prop` instead of `attr` to set radio checked

```js
$(function() {
  $("[name=customRadio][value='Agency Bill']").prop("checked", true);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="custom-control custom-control-inline custom-radio">
  <input type="radio" name="customRadio" class="custom-control-input" id="dirBill" value="Direct Bill" checked>
  <label class="custom-control-label" for="dirBill">Direct Bill</label>
</div>
<div class="custom-control custom-control-inline custom-radio">
  <input type="radio" name="customRadio" class="custom-control-input" value="Agency Bill" id="agencyBill">
  <label class="custom-control-label" for="agencyBill">Agency Bill</label>
</div>

<div id="test">

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#agencyBill").prop("checked", true);
$radios.filter('[value="Agency Bill"]').prop('checked', true);
$('[name="customRadio"]').filter('[value="Agency Bill]"]').attr("checked","checked");
```

Using proper quotes "" for selectors would solve the problem.

In your jsfiddle, include JQuery CDN for it to work.
https://jsfiddle.net/974duyzb/25/

Answer (score 0):

Because it contains a space character in the value and value is not wrapped in quotes, it won't do what you are intended to. So, you must wrap the values in quotes:

```
$radios.filter('[value="Agency Bill"]').prop('checked', true);
//$("[name=customRadio]").filter("[value='Agency Bill']").attr("checked","checked");
```

and instead of `attr()` use `.prop()` to mark it checked.

Comment: i tried using $radios.filter('[value="Agency Bill"]').prop('checked', true); still the same reult

Comment: @rajesh bro you have not added the jquery library to your fiddle. [updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/974duyzb/50/) check this.