# how to change child attribute jquery

Tags: jquery

I would like to use this from Bootstrap but with my Laravel Collective functions the option state button won't change to the correct state. So I want to change it myself with jQuery.

```
<div class="btn-group btn-group-toggle" data-toggle="buttons">
  <label class="btn btn-secondary active">
    <input type="radio" name="options" id="option1" autocomplete="off" checked> Active
  </label>
  <label class="btn btn-secondary">
    <input type="radio" name="options" id="option2" autocomplete="off"> Radio
  </label>
  <label class="btn btn-secondary">
    <input type="radio" name="options" id="option3" autocomplete="off"> Radio
  </label>
</div>
```

*(original HTML from getbootstrap.com)*

Which I re-wrote to:

```
<div id ="addproductsort" class="btn-group btn-group-toggle" data-toggle="buttons">
  <label id="productsort" class="btn btn-secondary active">
    {{Form::radio('options', 'one', false, ['name' => 'options', 'autocomplete' => 'off', 'class' => 'productsortoption'])}}
            one
  </label>
  <label id="productsort" class="btn btn-secondary">
    {{Form::radio('options', 'two', false, ['name' => 'options', 'id' => 'option2', 'autocomplete' => 'off', 'class' => 'productsortoption'])}}
            two
  </label>
  <label id="productsort" class="btn btn-secondary">
    {{Form::radio('options', 'three', false, ['name' => 'options', 'id' => 'option2', 'autocomplete' => 'off', 'class' => 'productsortoption'])}}
            three
  </label>
</div>
```

This is the script I got:

```
$('#productsort').each(function() {  
  $(this).on('click', function() {  
    if($(this).hasClass('active')) {
      $(this).children().attr( "checked", "checked" );
    };
  });
});
```

When I click the first button `one`, the state of the option `child` does change, but when I click the second or the third button nothing happens.

What's wrong in here?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: The `id` attribute should be unique in document but you have multiple `#productsort`. As i understand you want to check/uncheck checkbox on click of `label`, right?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to check a radio button with jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5665915/how-to-check-a-radio-button-with-jquery)

Comment: Only a maximum of one out of a group of radio buttons that  share the same `name` attribute value can be `checked`.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're looking for something like this example:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="btn-group" role="group" aria-label="Basic example">
  <label class="btn btn-secondary">
    <input type="radio" name="radio" />
  </label>
  <label class="btn btn-secondary">
    <input type="radio" name="radio" />
  </label>
  <label class="btn btn-secondary">
    <input type="radio" name="radio" />
  </label>
</div>
```

In this example, I've created 3 radio buttons and wrapped all of them by 3 labels.

Because the 3 radio buttons have the same name (`radio`), we don't need to use jquery to catch *onclick* event.

---

**Note:** `id` property **must** contain unique value. You cannot create multiple elements which have the same id value. In that case, you could use `class` instead. It's useful when you want to delete some element with a specific id.

---

> maybe i'm seeing i wrong, because my understanding was that "onclick" the option state should be set to "checked", but when i view the original HTML on 'getbootstrap' the checked state doesn't change, it's only set to "checked" on the first option

That's because of this line:

```
<label id="productsort" class="btn btn-secondary active">
    ...
</label>
```

The first label with the id `productsort` has class `active`. The second label and the third label don't have.

If you want to use jquery, you could try:

```
$('.productsort').on('click', function() {  
    // using "find" method to find an element that has class "active" from "addproductsort"
    // then, using "removeClass" method to remove the class "active" on the element
    $('#addproductsort').find('.active').removeClass('active');

    // all of the 3 labels don't have class "active" here
    // you can stop the code from here to check html code

    // we add class "active" to this label/element because it was clicked
    $(this).addClass('active').children().attr("checked", "checked");

    // or
    // $(this).addClass('active').children().prop("checked", true);
});
```

**NOTE:** I've change `id="productsort"` to `class="productsort"` in this example.

Comment: maybe i'm seeing i wrong, because my understanding was that "onclick" the option state should be set to "checked", but when i view the original HTML on 'getbootstrap' the checked state doesn't change, it's only set to "checked" on the first option

Comment: i didn't mean the class of the label, but the attribute of the radio '<input name="options" autocomplete="off" class="productsortoption" checked="checked" type="radio" value="one">', but if the "checked" state doesn't matter for the POST value then it's fixed like the first comment you gave me :)

Comment: @RMCS So what's happen if you follow me `.....children().prop("checked", true);`? Was something changed?

Comment: it works! the ".find" is what i need to check a state that is changed?

Comment: @RMCS It's used to find the label which has `active` class, then removing the `active` class. I've added some comments inside the code, you can check again.

Answer (score 0):

This is the final solution, i added

```
$('.productsortoption').removeAttr('checked');
```

to remove the "checked" state when ".productsort" isn't active.

```
$('.productsort').on('click', function() {  
     $('#addproductsort').find('.active').removeClass('active');
     $('.productsortoption').removeAttr('checked');
     $(this).addClass('active').children().attr("checked", "checked");
});
```

HTML

```
<div id ="addproductsort" class="w-100 btn-group btn-group-toggle" data-toggle="buttons">
    <label class="productsort">
        <input name="options" autocomplete="off" class="productsortoption" type="radio" value="Sale">
        one
    </label>
    <label class="productsort">
        <input name="options" id="option2" autocomplete="off" class="productsortoption" type="radio" value="two">
        two
    </label>
    <label class="productsort">
        <input name="options" id="option2" autocomplete="off" class="productsortoption" type="radio" value="three">
        three
    </label>
  </div>
```