# JQuery/HTML - Reset Buttons on Search Box Click

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I'm pretty rookie at this, so, apologies.
I've flattened my styling, so it's easier to paste in here, but the principles should still work.

I've got a list of items, a search field (which works) and filter buttons (which work).
What I need is for the filter buttons to reset to 'All' is active, when the search field is clicked, as the search field searches all items.

Could anyone advise...? I've tried all sorts of different methods but can't get the damn thing going.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <script src="vendor/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="vendor/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.0.0b1.js"></script>

  <!-- SEARCH LIST SCRIPT-->
  <script>
    function searchTable() {
      // Declare variables
      var input, filter, ul, li, a, i, txtValue;
      input = document.getElementById('imtListInput');
      filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
      ul = document.getElementById("imtList");
      li = ul.getElementsByTagName('li');

      // Loop through all list items, and hide those who don't match the search query
      for (i = 0; i < li.length; i++) {
        a = li[i].getElementsByTagName("a")[0];
        txtValue = a.textContent || a.innerText;
        if (txtValue.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
          li[i].style.display = "";
        } else {
          li[i].style.display = "none";
        }
      }
    }
  </script>

  <!-- TABLE SHOW HIDE SCRIPT-->
  <script>
    function show(champ) {
      $('ul li').hide()
      $('ul li:has(a.' + champ + ')').show()
    }
  </script>

  <!-- SEARCH CLICK SCRIPT-->
  <script>
    function searchClick() {
      $('ul li').show()

      //RESET SELECTED BUTTON TO 'ALL'

    }
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <div style="padding-bottom:10px;" class="btn-group btn-group-toggle" data-toggle="buttons">
    <label class="btn btn-primary btn-lg active">
                            <input type="radio" name="options" id="option1" autocomplete="off" checked onclick="$('ul li').show()"> All
                        </label>
    <label class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">
                            <input type="radio" name="options" id="option2" autocomplete="off" onclick="show(&quot;Section1&quot;)"> Section1
                        </label>
    <label class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">
                            <input type="radio" name="options" id="option3" autocomplete="off" onclick="show(&quot;Section2&quot;)"> Section2
                        </label>
  </div>

  <input type="text" id="imtListInput" onkeyup="searchTable()" onclick="searchClick()" placeholder="Search...">

  <ul id="imtList">
    <li><a class="Section1" href="#">File 1</a></li>
    <li><a class="Section1" href="#">File 2</a></li>
    <li><a class="Section1" href="#">File 3</a></li>
    <li><a class="Section1" href="#">File 4</a></li>
    <li><a class="Section1" href="#">File 5</a></li>
    <li><a class="Section2" href="#">File 6</a></li>
    <li><a class="Section2" href="#">File 7</a></li>
  </ul>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to check a radio button with jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5665915/how-to-check-a-radio-button-with-jquery)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select that radio button, and set its `checked` property to true:

```
  <script>
    function searchClick() {
      $('ul li').show()

      //RESET SELECTED BUTTON TO 'ALL'
      $('#option1').prop('checked', true);
      $('.btn-group-toggle label.active').removeClass('active');
      $('.btn-group-toggle label').first().addClass('active');

    }
  </script>
```

(Edit: Added reset of the `active` class on the labels as well.)

Comment: Seems to work in the example above, but when I add it back to my full styled document it doesn't highlight the correct button...

Comment: `<div style="padding-bottom:10px;" class="btn-group btn-group-toggle" data-toggle="buttons">
      <label class="btn btn-primary btn-lg active">
       <input type="radio" name="options" id="option1" autocomplete="off" checked onclick="$('ul li').show()"> All
      </label>
     </div>`

Comment: It is not clear from your question, what kind of custom formatting you are applying here. I’m guessing it has something to do with the `active` class on the label? Then you need to remove that from whichever label currently has it, and set it for the first one again.

Comment: $("#option1").trigger('click'); will work, however it then loses focus from the field...

Comment: I'm using Boostrap for the CSS. So the would-be radio buttons are actually buttons, they then switch between .btn-primary and .btn-primary:focus, .btn-primary.focus I suppose?

Comment: $( "#option1" ).focus(); works too - however again, it draws focus away permanently...

Comment: Have you checked my edit of the answer? Manually re-setting the active class should do the trick.

Comment: My sincerest apologies, I hadn't. That's fixed it. Perfect. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

At `searchTable` function you can add your radio elements by the `querySelectorAll()` and loop with for each to get the value of checked for each of them, so when you use search input, all `radioButtons` will be assigned to false, while search input is empty so `All RadioButton` will be checked to true since all list items appeared

```
function searchTable() {
                // Declare variables
                var input, filter, ul, li, a, i, txtValue, r;
                input = document.getElementById('imtListInput');
                filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
                ul = document.getElementById("imtList");
                li = ul.getElementsByTagName('li');
                
                r = document.querySelectorAll('input[type="radio"]');
                r.forEach(elem => {
                    elem.checked = false
                });
    
                // Loop through all list items, and hide those who don't match the search query
                for (i = 0; i < li.length; i++) {
                    a = li[i].getElementsByTagName("a")[0];
                    txtValue = a.textContent || a.innerText;
                    if (txtValue.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
                        li[i].style.display = "";
                    } else {
                        li[i].style.display = "none";
                    }
    
                    if (input.value === '') {
                        r[0].checked = true
                    }
                }
            }
```