# Select radio button according to returned value

Tags: javascript, php, html, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-3

When I edit an event without fullcalendar, I created these two radio buttons in the modal.

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
defaultView: 'month',
header: {
                language: 'PT',
                left: 'prev,next today',
                center: 'title',
                right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay,listWeek',
               
            },
            
            defaultDate: dia,
            editable: true,
            eventLimit: true, // allow "more" link when too many events
            selectable: true,
            selectHelper: true,
      
events: [

<?php foreach($events as $event): ?>
                {
                    id: '<?php echo $event['id']; ?>',
                    title: '<?php echo $event['nome']; ?>',
                    radio_one: '<?php echo ($event['contatou']=="Sim") ?  "checked" : "" ;  ?>',
                    radio_two: '<?php echo ($event['contatou']=="Não") ?  "checked" : "" ;  ?>',
                    
                },

            <?php endforeach; ?>
            ]
        });

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div class="modal fade" id="ModalEdit" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
          <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content">
            <form class="form-horizontal" method="POST" action="./updatevisitaLar1">
              <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">ALTERAR VISITA</h4>
              </div>
              <div class="modal-body">
                
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="titlee" class="col-sm-4 control-label">NOME UTENTE</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-8">
                      <select name="titlee" class="form-control" id="titlee">
                        <option value=""></option>
                          <?php        
                            $sql = "SELECT * FROM raddb.Utente WHERE ativo = '1' ORDER BY nome ASC";
                            $qr = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
                            while($ln = mysqli_fetch_assoc($qr)){
                            echo '<option value="'.$ln['codigo'].'">'.$ln['nome'].'</option>';
                            }
                          ?>  
                        </select>
                    </div>
                  </div>
          
          <div id="isolamento">

                  <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="switch_one" class="col-sm-4 control-label">CONTATOU VISITANTE</label>
                    <div class="switch-field">
                        <input type="radio" id="radio_one" name="switch_one" value="Sim" />
                        <label for="radio_one">SIM</label>
                        <input type="radio" id="radio_two" name="switch_one" value="Não" />
                        <label for="radio_two">NÃO</label>
                    </div>
                  </div>

                  <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="switch_two" class="col-sm-4 control-label">ALTERAÇÂO DA VISITA</label>
                    <div class="switch-field">
                        <input type="radio" id="radio_three" name="switch_two" value="Alt" />
                        <label for="radio_three">ALTERAÇÂO DE DATA</label>
                        <input type="radio" id="radio_four" name="switch_two" value="Canc" />
                        <label for="radio_four">CANCELOU VISITA</label>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  
                  </div>

                  <ul class="flex-outer">
               <div class="form-check">
                    <label class="toggle">
                        <input type="checkbox" name="delete"> <span class="label-text text-danger"> ELIMINAR TAREFA</span>
                    </label>
                </div>                
                 </ul> 
                
                  <input type="hidden" name="id" class="form-control" id="id">
                
                
              </div>
              <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal">Fechar</button>
                <button type="button" style="float: right" onclick="inserir_alter()" class="btn btn-primary">Guardar</button>
              </div>
            </form>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
```

When I return the value of the database option button, I want the value returned from the database to be selected. To do this I am doing it this way as I put it above:

```
radio_one: '<?php echo ($event['contatou']=="Sim") ?  "checked" : "" ;  ?>',
radio_two: '<?php echo ($event['contatou']=="Não") ?  "checked" : "" ;  ?>',
```

But it is not working.
I intend that the user when consulting the event in the modal, the radio selected appears according to the value returned from the database

I open the modal like this:

```
eventRender: function(event, element) {
                element.bind('dblclick', function() {
                    
                    console.log(event.cancelou);
                    $('#ModalEdit #id').val(event.id);
                    $('#ModalEdit #titlee').val(event.titlee);
                    $('#ModalEdit #response').val(event.response);
                    $('#ModalEdit #contacte').val(event.contacte);
                    $('#ModalEdit #title1e').val(event.title1);
                    $('#ModalEdit #contact1e').val(event.contact1);
                    $('#ModalEdit #start1').val(moment(event.start).format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss'));
                    $('#ModalEdit #end1').val(moment(event.end).format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss'));
                    $('#ModalEdit #DataRegisto').val(event.DataRegisto);
                    $('#ModalEdit #Colaborador').val(event.Colaborador);

                    $('#ModalEdit').modal('show');
                });
```

Comment: More context needed. There seems to be no link between these two pieces of code

Comment: @ADyson I have already edited the question. So that way you can understand the problem I have?

Comment: Thanks. But how are you making the modal be opened? That part seems to still be missing. I can't see any connection between your calendar and your modal.

Comment: @ADyson I already added the code that opens the modal

Comment: Ok thanks. So...in that code you aren't doing anything with the radio_one and radio_two values. So how are you expecting that to affect your modal? You need to use those values to control the selection of the radio button, similar to the way you are using other fields from the event to set the value of the other fields in the modal. Have you tried anything? Was there a specific problem?

Comment: @ADyson I added these lines of code to the code: `$('#ModalEdit #radio_one').val(event.contatou);` and  `$('#ModalEdit #radio_two').val(event.contatou);` 
but it doesn't work the same

Comment: This should help you: [How to check a radio button with jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5665915/how-to-check-a-radio-button-with-jquery)

Comment: @ADyson I'm putting it like this: `$('#ModalEdit #radio_one').prop("checked",true);` and `$('#ModalEdit #radio_two').prop("checked",true);` and you should select the first radio button, but always select the second one, which says "No" and you should select what says "Yes" because it is what is returned from the database

Comment: Well you're telling it to select the first one. And then you're telling it to select the second one immediately after. You aren't using the value returned from the database to decide which one to select.

Comment: @ADyson Ok, can you explain how I have to do it? I'm not seeing how to get the value that is returned from the database

Comment: @ADyson I still couldn't solve this problem, can't you help?

Comment: It's like you read my mind, I am typing an answer right now. Give me a few minutes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not using the values you're setting in the fullCalendar events to actually do anything. And having the two separarate radio_one and radio_two values doesn't make a lot of sense really either.

Here's an approach which should work:

```
events: [
    <?php foreach($events as $event): ?>
    {
        id: '<?php echo $event['id']; ?>',
        title: '<?php echo $event['nome']; ?>',
        switch_one: '<?php echo $event['contatou'];  ?>'
    },
    <?php endforeach; ?>
]
```

and

```
$("input[name='switch_one'][value='" + event.switch_one + ']").prop("checked",true);
```

This uses the actual value in your field to find the radio with the matching value within the group of radio buttons, and sets it "checked" property to true, which makes it selected. The concept was taken from the example in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13414984/5947043).